# How do you update table using local variables or user-defined functions?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to update my table with setting the "username" to be a product of "name".

Here is my example:

```
declare @username varchar(128)

-- create local table
declare @t table (name varchar(32), username varchar(32))
insert into @t(name, username) values ('Johnny Cash','')

-- update rows, set "username" to its correct value
;with mytable as (select * from @t)
update mytable
-- this is really messy, I want to use some local variables or a user-defined function here to compute the username...
set username = lower(substring(name, 0, charindex(' ', name)) + '.' + substring(name, charindex(' ', name)+1, len(name)))

-- select all rows so I can see them
;with mytable as (select * from @t)
select * from mytable
```

For each row, I want the username to be the same as name but with some modifications.

Is this possible?

To clarify, I want the row with name "Johnny Cash" to have a username "johnny.cash"

Comment: What column (`name`,or `username`) do you want to update ?

Comment: I want to update the "username" column

Answer (score 1):

Simple `update` statement would also work, no need to use *variable* :

```
update @t
     set username = replace(lower(name), ' ', '.')
```

EDIT :

If you want only single value to be update with help of variable then you can do :

```
select @username = replace(lower(name), ' ', '.')
from @t
where name = @username;
```

Comment: Point is, I want to know how to use variables. My question is just an example of a very simple way of computing a new value for the column. But what about more complex value computations?

Comment: @gromit190. . . No, you can't update with variable. Since, it holds single value.

Comment: How can I update the **username** with some logic then?

Comment: @gromit190. . . What logic do you want to apply ? Edit the question with logic.

Comment: Okay forget about "logic" for a minute. What if I want my username to be **(firstname).(lastname)** where firstname is the first character of "name" up to the space character, and lastname is "name" from space character and the rest of name string. This is too complex for a single-line statement. I want to be able to use some kind of local variables or whatever so that I can code a more complex way of computing the updated value.

Comment: Should I be using functions instead?

Comment: @gromit190. . . Then replace name with username instead.

Comment: I've updated my question, the "set" statement is a complete mess but it works. Is there some way that the set statement can be a separate function, consisting of some local variables or similar?

Comment: @gromit190 STOP - you are trying to apply concepts and techniques that are not appropriate to SQL. You think in terms of RBAR when you should think in terms of sets. By trying to force the use of such logic, you are writing inefficient (and error prone) sql. That is a basic struggle that ever 3/4GL programmer encounters when learning tsql. Can you do what you ask? Yes, but it is not a good idea.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @SMor. So am I to conlcude that there simply is no way to update a column by the values of other columns?